# Powershell script for SQL Azure back up to Microsoft Azure Blob

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, powershell-2.0

I want to take SQL Azure back up to Azure Blob storage using PowerShell. I have used the following script, but it is popping up for credential whenever I try to run.

I will be using this script from windows task scheduler, so how can I put user id and password inside PowerShell script so that it won't ask for username/password for subscription?

```
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Database to export
$DatabaseName = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$ServerName = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$serverAdmin = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$serverPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxx" 
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $serverAdmin, $securePassword

# Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
$bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"


# Storage account info for the BACPAC
$BaseStorageUri = "https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/"
$BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a non-interactive login in your script. Just modify your script as below:

```
##login Azure  
$subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$username = "<username>"
$password = "<password>"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

Note: you cannot login non-intereractively to Azure using a Microsoft Live account, such as *@hotmail.com, *@outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two ways you can achieve this.

The first is to use the `credential` parameter as part of the `Login-AzureRMAccount` call.  You can create a PSCredential in the powershell code and then use that.  For example:  `Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential`

The second, and probably the safer/more secure way, is to create a service principal and then place the certificate on the machine in question.  You can find instructions on how to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal).  After you have that created, you can use the `Login-AzureRMAccount` with the `-ServicePrincipal`parameter.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#provide-credentials-through-powershell) for more information.